# What view events are triggered when a view is removed from a region?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I am currently using Marionette 2.4.1.

Within view A, if I remove view B from the region belonging to view A, what events are triggered on view B on emptying the region?

I know on view B, `onDestroy` and `onBeforeDestroy` are invoked however I am wondering what events are triggered if that region includes `{preventDestroy: true}`? If I use that, `onDestroy` and `onBeforeDestroy` are not called but I can't figure out what event is triggered on view B. It seems like there are none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your LayoutView is called view A, it has a region. In that region an ItemView called B is shown. When A empties it's region, events will be fired on view B (`before:destroy` and `destroy`) - this happens regardless if view B was shown in it's region with `preventDestroy: true` or without.

`preventDestroy: true` is used when you want to show one view in a region, then another in the same region without destroying the previous view. So, in this example:

---

1. Show view B in a region.
2. Show (without `preventDestroy`) a new view (C) in the same region - will cause view B to be destroyed and to fire destroy events.

---

1. Show view B in a region.
2. Show (using `preventDestroy`) a new view (C) in the same region - will *not* cause view B to be destroyed, thus no destroy events will be fired.

---

**Edit**

In the first case, these events are fired on the views:

```
::: B :::  before:destroy
::: B :::  destroy
::: C :::  before:render
::: A :::  childview:before:render
::: C :::  render
::: A :::  childview:render
::: C :::  before:show
::: A :::  childview:before:show
::: C :::  before:attach
::: A :::  childview:before:attach
::: C :::  attach
::: A :::  childview:attach
::: C :::  dom:refresh
::: A :::  childview:dom:refresh
::: C :::  show
::: A :::  childview:show
```

In the second case, these events are fired on the views:

```
::: C :::  before:render
::: A :::  childview:before:render
::: C :::  render
::: A :::  childview:render
::: C :::  before:show
::: A :::  childview:before:show
::: C :::  before:attach
::: A :::  childview:before:attach
::: C :::  attach
::: A :::  childview:attach
::: C :::  dom:refresh
::: A :::  childview:dom:refresh
::: C :::  show
::: A :::  childview:show
```

Note that in the last case, view B doesn't fire destroy events, and no other events either.

Comment: Correct, are there any events that are fired when using preventDestroyed similarly to `before:destroy`? I don't see them in the source code so I guess they don't exist.

Comment: That's right, I added an edit in the answer. No other events on view B.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)